# Why can I run my app on my device from XCode but not profile it?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to profile my app. I can run it on device from Xcode but when I try to profile it I get an error message in Instruments 'Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.xxxx.xxxx was denied. The app must be signed with a Development Entity (e.g., 'iOS Developer).'

I have edited my scheme so that 'Run xxxx' and 'Profile xxxx' are both set to use my Release Configuration.

My code signing identity is set to an specific iPhone Developer identity (i.e., 'iPhone Developer: myname (X234X234X234)'), not 'iOS Developer', so I don't think there is any confusion about which identity to use. I do have 2 developer identities, one for Enterprise Distribution.

I think my app is properly signed because it runs. Any idea why profiling it fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ran into the exact same issue earlier today.

Under Schemes -> Edit Schemes

Select Profile : and switch to Debug (should be Release by default).

This is pretty weird though. Should be Debug by Default (Hey Apple!)

Comment: I have custom schemes such as `DebugStaging` that are signed with a development identity. Yet, I still get this problem. I deleted the default schemes. Any advice on how I can solve this?

Comment: @Awesome-o I'm not sure I can help you without a screenshot. IIRC, all you need to do is set the Build Configuration to "Debug" for any custom schemes you may have.

Comment: The build configuration is set to `DebugStaging` there is not `Debug` option. What's interesting is I can still use profiler on our `DebugProduction` scheme with `DebugProduction` build configuration. I'll investigate more what the difference is between these two and post it here.

Comment: That would be very helpful, as I am, as well, not sure what seems to be the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, but what did work was... deleting derived data, then building running the app on my device, closing the app, then opening instruments and selecting my app from the "Choose Target" drop down. It then would use my `DebugProduction` scheme/config settings since that's what was last loaded to the device. Sorry I couldn't pin down exactly what the issue was :\

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you sorted it out. This happens, more than you'd think. Hopefully your answer helps someone.

Comment: As an edit (can't seem to edit comments), this fix worked on `DebugStaging`; `DebugProduction` was already working.